# Are there other human settlements in Gran Pulse?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I have just played the first Final Fantasy XIII, when I arrive at Oerba Village, I can see the remnants of a small city and a still powered mining site...

Are there any other human settlements in Gran Pulse?

Comment: Do you mean during the events of 13? Or at ANY point during the history of the world?

Comment: i mean during the event of FF13.
Fang and Vanille seem too calm after finding their town deserted,
i never find they mention it in game . .

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one tribe that exists on Gran Pulse: The Farseers, the tribe that Noel belongs to in XIII-2. There's no evidence that they were present on Cocoon, and they existed long before the events of the game (As you spend a lot of time exploring their ancient ruins in XIII-2.) So it's safe to say there must have been populated settlements on Pulse, even if you don't get to see them in-game.

Comment: as i far as i know Farseer is a tribe from Noel time which is 700 years i the future.
what i mean is are there any other Pulsian when FFXII takes event beside Fang and Vanille.

Answer (score 1):

There are Paddra ruins in the Yaschas Massif.